# Git core.autocrlf for mixed Windows and OSX environment

Tags: git

Git's `core.autocrlf` option is meant for dealing with line endings when checking out and committing code, and Github has some pretty nice documentation on it here: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

However, I'm in sort of an edge case scenario where I'm checking out the code in Windows, making changes there, then copying the file to OSX and committing.

What should my `core.autocrlf` settings be in this scenario?

Comment: Wait, what?  Why aren't you committing via your Windows machine?

Comment: Long story, but I'm working on getting to that point. Sometimes you have to work around your problem for a minute then go back and solve the root of the issue. Obviously this scenario is not sustainable :)

Answer (score 0):

> What should my core.autocrlf settings be in this scenario?

If a file with CRLF endings accidentally gets introduced in LF-world, then you may want Git to fix it. You can tell Git to convert CRLF to LF on commit but not the other way around by setting `core.autocrlf` to `input`:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

This setup should leave you with CRLF endings in Windows checkouts, but LF endings on Mac and Linux systems and in the repository.